# Can't test a function called inside useEffect with state dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jestjs

I have a component that has an useLayoutEffect with a state dependency.
Inside this useEffect there's a function call that receives the new state value as a parameter.

The setState of the useLayoutEffect state is triggered by a childComponent.

I'm trying to write a unit test that reproduces the following scenario: When the state is changed, verify if the useEffect has triggered and called this function inside it with the correct params.

Here's my code:

```
const stateGroup: StateGroup = {
    state1: useState<number>(0),
    state2: useState<number>(0),
    state3: useState<number>(0)
  };
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    handleStateUpdate();
  }, [stateGroup.state1[0], stateGroup.state2[0], stateGroup.state3[0]]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <ContentCard>
        <ShowMobile>
          <TitleConfiguration />
          <hr />
        </ShowMobile>
        <ChildComponentU  
          stateGroup={stateGroup} 
        />
      </ContentCard>
    </>
  )
}
```

I put fictional for data protection purpose, but it represents the exact scenario.